# Pull Data from file based on login id java

Tags: java

What i'm trying to do is whenever i login with a specific id it will pull the school name based on the id that was typed.For example i have this in my file [testing.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkisW.png)  and i login to 0114343 and want to validate that if the school is "School of Communication" it will change the label to "SOC"

This is my code so far but it doesn't work It will only display SOC regardless of which id i logged in. Any help would be appreciated thanks you.

**LoginClass**

```
public class TestingProgram {

JButton button1,button2;
JLabel label;
JTextField idField,passwdField;
BufferedWriter toFile;
BufferedReader validation;
String valuesArray[]={};
String idTitle;
int exists=0;
public TestingProgram()
{

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();   
    JPanel pnl = new JPanel();

    //Buttons
    button1 = new JButton("Add");
    button2 = new JButton("Login"); 

    //TextField
    idField = new JTextField(15);
    passwdField = new JTextField(15);

    pnl.add(button1);
    pnl.add(button2);
    pnl.add(idField);
    pnl.add(passwdField);


    button2.addActionListener((ActionEvent e )->{
       Validation();
    });

    frame.add(pnl,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

   public String getIdTitle()
{
    idTitle = idField.getText();
    return idTitle;
}

public void Validation()
{
 try{
        validation = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("testing.txt"));
        String values=null;
        while((values = validation.readLine())!=null)
            {
                valuesArray = values.split(",");
                if(idField.getText().equals(valuesArray[0]) && passwdField.getText().equals(valuesArray[1]))
                {
                    exists = 1;
                    break;
                }                    
            }       
                 if(exists==1)
                {
                    SecondTest sec = new SecondTest();
                    sec.second();
                    sec.frame.setTitle(getIdTitle());
                }
                 else
                 {
                     System.out.println("Does not exsits in file");
                 }
        }

        catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }            

}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   new TestingProgram();
}

}
```

**Second Class**

```
public class SecondTest 
{
JFrame frame;
JButton button;
JLabel label;
JPanel panel;
BufferedReader validation;
String valuesArray[] = {};
String school;
public void second()
{
    frame = new JFrame();
    button = new JButton("Button");
    label = new JLabel("");
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(button);
    panel.add(label);

    try{
        validation = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("testing.txt"));
        String values=null;
        while((values=validation.readLine())!=null)
        {
            valuesArray=values.split(",");
            if(valuesArray[2].equals("SchoolofCommunication"))
            {
                school = "SOC";
                break;
            }
            else if(valuesArray[2].equals("SchoolofEngineering"))
            {
                school = "SOE";
                break;
            }         
        }
         if(school.equals("SOC"))
            {
                label.setText("SOC");
            }
            else 
            {
                label.setText("SOE");
            }


    }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }     

    frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(450,450);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`second()` doesn't have the ID context.  The while loop just reads the file and SOC happens to be the first entry in the file so it immediately breaks.

```
    while((values=validation.readLine())!=null) {
        valuesArray=values.split(",");
        if(valuesArray[2].equals("SchoolofCommunication")) {
            school = "SOC";
            break;
        }

        // this else branch is not reachable based on the contents of the file
        else if(valuesArray[2].equals("SchoolofEngineering")) {
            school = "SOE";
            break;
        }

    }
```

so you need to pass in the ID context:

```
second(String id)
```

and use it in the while loop to find the relevant line in the file:

```
    while((values=validation.readLine())!=null) {
        valuesArray=values.split(",");
        if(valuesArray[0].equals(id) && valuesArray[2].equals("SchoolofCommunication")) {
            school = "SOC";
            break;
        } else if((valuesArray[0].equals(id) && valuesArray[2].equals("SchoolofEngineering")) {
            school = "SOE";
            break;
        }
    }
```